# why react component state is not updating

Tags: reactjs

I have a Like component on a product page. The component is a button that when clicked, that product is put in the states liked array. The problem is when I change products and click the button the second product is not added to the array, rather it replaces the other product that's in the array. For example. I click on a shirt, I see that its been added to the array. I go back and click another shirt and instead of both shirts being in the array only the last shirt I clicked is in the array. Below is the product details page that includes the Like component and the Like page

```
class Details extends Component {

    render() {

        const { id } = this.props.match.params;

        const productList = this.props.products.map(product => {
            if (product.product_id == id) {
                return (
                    <div className="container product_details">
                        <div className="left">
                            <div className="images">
                                <img className="detail_main-photo" src={product.image} />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="right">
                            <h2 className="detail_heading">{product.title}</h2>

                            <p className="detail_description">{product.description}</p>
                            <div className="detail_size">


                            </div>
                            <p className="detail_price">${product.price}</p>
                            <Likes product={product} />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                )

            }

        })


        return (

            <div >


                {productList}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Details;







class Likes extends Component {

    state = {
        likes: []
    }

    addLike = () => {
        const button = document.querySelector('.submit')
        const Liked = this.state.likes.findIndex(like => {
            return like.id === this.props.product.product_id
        })
        if (Liked) {
            const { product } = this.props;

            const newLike = {
                id: product.product_id,
                image: product.image[0],
                title: product.title,
                price: product.price
            }

            this.setState({
                likes: [...this.state.likes, newLike]
            })
        }
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <button className="submit" onClick={this.addLike}>Add To Wishlist</button>
        )
    }
}
export default Likes;
```

Comment: where is the code that handle the click button ? By the way when you have a list of elements in react, you should add the `key` attribute which would be the productId in your case

Comment: The Like button is there for each shirt, so it a difference instance of the class. So each Like will have its own state. To have a list of Liked shirts you should save the Like array in product details class